# How does fortran compilers optimize operations in routines' arguments

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, fortran

I am using subroutines in Fortran 90 which have too arguments. On the first call of these subroutines the second one is useless but still present. I know that this is not a nice way to do things but for historical reasons it has been made like this.

For example:

```
CALL myroutine(A, B + C)
```

where:

```
SUBROUTINE myroutine (A, B)
    IF(.NOT. first) THEN
       !Using B in a way or another..
    ELSE
       !Other operations, not using B.
    END IF
END SUBROUTINE routine
```

I am using gfortran 4.4.7 to compile with -O3.

I would like to know if the operation B + C, useless when it's the first call to myroutine because the second argument is unused, is performed or not...

Moreover, precise compiling optimizations are new to me, and I would be interested in knowing which resources I can refer to when facing such questions.

Comment: I suspect that `B+C` is executed because an argument has to be evaluated before it can be passed to (and ignored by) the subroutine. But I have no authoritative source for that...

Comment: I share @Floris' suspicion. As for precise optimisations, if you can't get what you want from your compiler's documentation (and I bet it's silent on this point) you .can learn a lot by examining the assembler issued by the compiler

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite an answer to the question, more a comment on possibly optimizing the code.

As Floris & High Performance Mark comment, it is likely that the compiler still will execute `B+C` even if the subroutine does not use it. As an alternative to passing `B+C` to the subroutine every time, you could use the flag `OPTIONAL` for the variable `B` in the subroutine, combined with the `PRESENT` inquiry. You could then eliminate the `B+C` in the first call to the subroutine and then add it in for the second call:

```
PROGRAM main
    IMPLICIT NONE
    ! definitions of a, b, c, etc

    CALL myroutine(a)
    CALL myroutine(a,b+c)

  CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE myroutine(a,b)
       <TYPE> :: a
       <TYPE>, OPTIONAL :: b
       IF(PRESENT(b)) THEN
          ! operations using b and a
       ELSE
          ! operations using a only
       ENDIF
    END SUBROUTINE
END PROGRAM
```

Where `<TYPE>` is whatever type `A` and `B` are supposed to be.